# Angularjs expressions doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, eclipse

I'm new to AngularJS.

I started to write a basic code, but the result doesn't give me as expected. The result give me as `10+20={{ 10+20 }}`. But instead I need to see `10+20=30`

Here is what I tried.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="lib/angular.min(2).js"></script>
</head>
<body data-ng-app>
    <div>
        10+20={{ 10+20 }}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using eclipse. The `angular.min(2).js` file is in `lib` folder under `WebContent`. The HTML page is under `WebContent` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Check your angular.js script file is loading properly by looking at the network tab. The following works fine.

**DEMO**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body data-ng-app>
    <div>
        10+20={{ 10+20 }}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks. It worked fine. But I'm wondering why the angular.js script is not loading properly

Comment: its always better to use some package manager to load your scripts or use online cdns rather than having a static file. did it work?

Answer (score 0):

Remove WebContent from the URL. If your html file is in WebContent directory, your URL should be

```
<script src="lib/angular.min(2).js"></script>
```

Comment: that is what he mentioned in the quesiton

Answer (score -1):

have you tried to use the script in js like this:

```
<body ng-app="main">
 10+20={{10+20}}
</body>
<script>
var app=angular.module("main",[])
</script>
```